# Sublime like fuzzy search in emacs?

Tags: emacs, fuzzy-search, ido

I'm new to emacs and started loving it.

Well, 
I work on NodeJs and other java script stuff. I tried flx-ido for fuzzy search but it's not searching in sub directories.
Is there any fuzzy search plugin available in emacs that's similar to sublime fuzzy search.

I don't have any specific project meta data hence i don't want to use projectile or helm etc..,
Any will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I don't have any specific project meta data hence i don't want to use projectile or…" Do you use version control? Even the presence of a `.git/` or `.hg/` directory is enough metadata for something like projectile to work.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno what Sublime fuzzy search is like, but with [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) you can use several kinds of fuzzy search over a directory hierarchy, i.e., through subdirs.

You can use the different fuzzy matching methods with any Icicles commands, including the file-searching commands.

The relevant Icicles doc is this:

- [Completion Methods and Styles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_Methods_and_Styles) - different kinds of fuzzy matching
- [Find Files Anywhere](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#FindFilesAnywhere) - searching a file hierarchy

For example, you can use command `icicle-locate-file` to search a under a directory for files whose names or contents match a search pattern, which can be a regexp or make use of fuzzy matching.

Comment: from icicles.el: `;; Author: Drew Adams`.  coincidence?